# What happens when I edit a question still in the review queue?

Tags: support, review, suggested-edits

Say I edit a question or an answer. After submitting the edit suggestion, I notice something else that could be improved on it.

If I `edit` the question a second time, will it appear twice in the review queue, or will the newer change replace the older edit suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will replace the previous suggestion.  There will not be two suggested edits in the queue.

Comment: Is this still the case if the edit has already been reviewed by one of the two/three required to approve the edit?

Comment: @IQAndreas Yes, so long as the edit has not been applied yet.  If it has already been approved/rejected, then a new suggestion is made.